# How to stop animations?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I am using this code to make an animation. My question is how do I stop the animation? Don't tell me to change the repeat count either. I want the animation to work until I say stop. Is there a method that I can use to achieve this?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:INFINITY];
[[menuViewOne loadBut] setFrame:CGRectMake(230, 35, 150, 25)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use start stop animations using blocks. commitAnimations is not recommended by the documentation.

From the docs.

> Use of this method is discouraged in
>   iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the
>   block-based animation methods to
>   specify your animations instead.